# What is the meaning of fuzz factor?

Tags: keras

I came across this documentation in keras for the list of
[backend functions](https://keras.io/backend/#backend-functions)

One of which was `keras.backend.epsilon()`

The documentation says that it returns the value of the fuzz factor used in numeric expressions. However I could not understand what fuzz factor is and how is it used in the context of neural networks. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The epsilon in Keras is a small floating point number used to generally avoid mistakes like divide by zero. An example of its usage is here in the Keras code for calculation of mean absolute percentage error https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/c67adf1765d600737b0606fd3fde48045413dee4/keras/losses.py#L22

```
from . import backend as K

def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred):
diff = K.abs((y_true - y_pred) / K.clip(K.abs(y_true),
                                        K.epsilon(),
                                        None))
return 100. * K.mean(diff, axis=-1)
```

Comment: This doesn't address the fuzz factor question.

Comment: I suppose fuzz (the exact word used in keras docs and all of codebase for the epsilon) is another word for distortion?